# Android Studio - SAXParseException when accessing wikipedia page

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, sax

I have a very unusual issue with Android Studio, which started 4 days ago (i assume after the update).
The problem is: The exception is thrown when trying to read (parse) any page, whether it is wikipedia, google, yahoo, some java documentation..., but when i write the same code in Eclipse, everything is working fine.
So, here is the code from the calling class (activity):

```
    `new Thread(new ImgCrawlerThread("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_(comic_book)")).start();`
```

And here is the code from the ImgCrawlerThread:

```
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        //Thread.sleep(60000);
        URL url = new URL(httpsurl);
        HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        DocumentBuilder db;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(https.getInputStream());
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
        System.out.println(nodes.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
        https.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The exception in Android Studio is thrown from the code: 
`Document doc = db.parse(https.getInputSteam())`

The result from the Eclipse execution looks like this:

`//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/4d/BatmanComicIssue1%2C1940.png/250px-BatmanComicIssue1%2C1940.png`

And from the Android Studio:

```
     `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /img read: a (position:END_TAG </a>@43:317 in java.io.InputStreamReader@1f213bb3) 
System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)
System.err:     at com.finki.filip.crawlingtest.CrawlerAsync.doInBackground(CrawlerAsync.java:61)
System.err:     at com.finki.filip.crawlingtest.CrawlerAsync.doInBackground(CrawlerAsync.java:37)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)`
```

I would be thankful to anyone who could give me a rational opinion about this irrational problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML != XML

XML parsers are pretty strict about input grammar.  Web browsers on the other hand have to contend with mismatched tags, etc and are much more forgiving.  So trying to parse web pages with an XML parser is going to be a losing battle.

Even Google has the same problem inside Android.  If you look at the source code to `Html.fromHtml()` which converts HTML into their marked-up `SpannableString`, you will discover that they use an open-source library called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org).  This allows "tag-soup" HTML to be parsed like XML.  It will create a sensible DOM for you out of really broken HTML markup.  I suggest you look at jsoup for your application.

Comment: Yeah, i know that **jsoup** is a good option. But my goal was to use something that is native to java, cause when i use many external jars android studio fails to run the application with exit code -1 (i suppose because of a lack of heap memory). Anyway, i deleted my all external jars except **jsoup** and everything is working fine. Also, i noticed that when i click on `System.err: at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:107)` it gives me two sources: the one located in the JAVA_HOME directory, and other in AppData used by AndroidStudio. The later is unnecessary.

Comment: So, in my opinion, the one that is causing the problem is the DocumentBuilder.java source in the AppData/Android/platform/sources folder rather than that in C:/ProgramFiles/Java, because when i was comparing the two pieces of code, they were different. And to mention again, this happened after the update, not before that. Strange, isn't it ?!